# asp.net how to store text box values(tables) thru postbacks

Tags: asp.net

I have created a dynamic matrix display using asp:table/cell combination. and added a textbox displaying a value in each cell. at this point i am creating a view state, which sto res the complete table.

Now if i update the text boxes and click on save, i get the empty table(because of postback) and also the values in ViewState are stale - they are not the updated user values.

so is there a way to create a view state on each text box change. how can i store the edited textbox values?

Comment: How do you know viewstate is stale?  This kind of question is usually the result of not recreating controls until after viewstate has been wired up.  I think you'll need to post your dynamic generation code to get any meaningful answers.  Any reason you're not using a DataGridView with TemplateField's?

Comment: Why aren't you using asp.net's viewstate?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to store the text boxes values because they all ready posted back.

You only need to read them from the post back.

```
Request.Form[YourTextBox.UniqueID]
```

Now if you wish to save them on viewState you can use a code like

```
string YouData
{
    set 
    { 
        ViewState["cYouData"] = value;
    }
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["cYouData"] != null)
            return ViewState["cYouData"].ToString();
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

But the only reason to do that is to understand if something has change, and to find if something has change a simple hash can do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Detect the PostBack and re-load the values there:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
{   
  // initial load 
} 
else 
{   
  // postback    
}
```